# pull dl tag in bootstrap to the left

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How can I override the `dl` tag in bootstrap so that it does not have any width (by default it has width of 160). I want the `dt` field to be on the left. Also, how can I add more white space between the two rows?

I tried to override the width but it didn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6357/embedded/result/

Example without my changes http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6356/embedded/result/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
.dl-horizontal dt{
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    width: auto;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

.dl-horizontal dd{
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6358/embedded/result/)**

Comment: Um, the fiddle doesn't show a `horizontal` definition list? terms `<dt>` appear on separate lines from definitions `<dd>` in this fiddle